# Unregister sys.ShutdownHookThread if thread is successful?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, shutdown-hook

I have a `Future` in Scala `2.11` that is controlled by a worker actor in Akka. The Future is executed by the worker and the worker reports back to a central actor to report success/failure and requests more work.

The futures handled by the worker are long-running and computations can take up to 15 minutes to complete depending on complexity of the task. There's a 100% chance that a deployment can happen in mid-computation, and I'm going to just let it crash. However, I do need to do some very small clean-up, so I've implemented the following `sys.ShutdownHookThread` in the future itself:

```
sys.ShutdownHookThread {
  logger.info(s"Computation was killed mid-task for user ${set.userId}. Recovering state...")
  closeProcessingState
}
```

**My question** is this: if I have registered a shutdown hook, will it unregister itself when the future is complete? Checking the API docs, the description says it is "self-unregistering" but it doesn't seem to indicate what causes it to unregister itself.

Basically, if the JVM shuts down hours later, I don't want a thousand shutdown hooks running because they didn't self-unregister.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs doesn't say it's "self-unregistering". It says: `It knows how to unregister itself.`. It means you can call the method `remove` in the instance of `ShutdownHookThread`.

This `ShutdownHookThread` is just a helper for [java.lang.Runtime#addShutdownHook](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)). Have a look at the implementation [it's quite simple](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/sys/ShutdownHookThread.scala#L19).

In other words, you are responsible for unregistering it.

Comment: Yep it's that simple. I created an optional reference to the hook at remove it with `shutdownHook.map { hook => hook.remove() }`